# Rstudio installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status and lots of "#include nested too deeply"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am very new to R so I am struggling to fix this issue. I am trying to install ggplot2. I am running the latest version of R (4.0.3). Everytime I try to install, get this error:

> In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
>
> /usr/local/include/stdint.h:2:10: error: #include nested too deeply
>
> #include <stddef.h>

for *many* lines, followed by:

> Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘isoband’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependencies ‘digest’, ‘glue’, ‘isoband’, ‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’ are not available for package ‘ggplot2’
>
> removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.0.3/lib/R/library/ggplot2’
>
> Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in ‘/private/var/folders/v9/rbssx21x0tl40q94t7xl6ggh0000gn/T/RtmprVT4eu/downloaded_packages’

I have tried

- restarting Rstudio
- `install.packages("ggplot", dependencies=TRUE)`
- `install.packages("ggplot2")`
- reinstalling Rstudio

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: based on `/usr/local/Cellar/...`, probably MacOS + homebrew?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, meant to say that. MacOS and homebrew is correct.

Comment: How did you install R? On MacOS, I would strongly recommend to download the compiled binaries from here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/